# React form handling can not get input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I made a simple form validation custom hook which for some reason is only working for one out of the two inputs in my page.

This is the custom hook I made.

```js
export default function useForm(initialState) {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialState);

  const handleValue = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({
      ...formValues,
      [name]: {
        ...formValues[name],
        value: value,
      },
    });
    console.dir(name, value, formValues);
  };

  const handleError = (ref, error) => {
    const { name } = ref.current;
    setFormValues({
      ...formValues,
      [name]: {
        ...formValues[name],
        error: error,
      },
    });
    console.dir(name, formValues);
  };
  return [formValues, handleValue, handleError];
}
```

Calling the hook.

```js
const [formValues, handleValue, handleError] = useForm({
  phone: { value: "", error: "" },
  password: { value: "", error: "" },
})
```

This is the input that **does not** work.

```js
<input
    name="phone"
    id="phone"
    className="phone"
    type="number"
    placeholder="Mobile Number"
    value={formValues.phone.value}
    ref={inputPhoneRef}
    onInput={handleValue}
    onFocus={onFocus}
    autoFocus
/>
```

This is the input that **does** work.

```js
<input
    name="password"
    id="password"
    className="password"
    type="password"
    placeholder="Password"
    value={formValues.password.value}
    ref={inputPasswordRef}
    onInput={handleValue}
    onFocus={onFocus}
/>
```

If i try to console.log the `formValue` object only the password value gets updates and in case of errors too only the password errors get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me, Check sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-satoshi-f789w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Even in the sandbox, only the password value is returned the phone value is logged as an empty string on input.

Comment: @HitenDalmia it cannot be since the value is set to the form state value, it wouldn't be able to reflect if its not saved in state. It works in the sandbox, check the console.

Comment: I did check the console, I've attached a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/vNpvhrt.png.

Comment: @HitenDalmia you cannot type "letters" into a number input, how did you manage to do that, nothing wrong with your code, if you want to type text into phone number input change the input type to ```type="text"```  it will work.